# Improving VBA Macro in Word to automatically create file relating to document name and location

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently using a macro to add an incrementing document number to the footer of a document. The problem is it uses a global "settings.txt" file.

I want to apply this macro to many documents and each much have its own record of the incrementing number.

I am not a pro a VBA/Macro writing so I do need some pretty clear instructions or copy and pasteable code.

```
Sub SerialNumber()
'
' SerialNumber Macro
'
'
Dim Message  As String, Title  As String, Default  As String, NumCopies  As Long
 Dim Rng1   As Range

 ' Set prompt.
Message = "Enter the number of copies that you want to print"
 ' Set title.
Title = "Print"
 ' Set default.
Default = "1"

' Display message, title, and default value.
Dim SerialNumber As String
NumCopies = Val(InputBox(Message, Title, Default))
 SerialNumber = System.PrivateProfileString("W:\settings.txt", _
 "MacroSettings", "SerialNumber")

 If SerialNumber = "" Then
     SerialNumber = 1
 End If

 Set Rng1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SerialNumber").Range
 Counter = 0

 While Counter < NumCopies
     Rng1.Delete
     Rng1.Text = SerialNumber
     ActiveDocument.PrintOut
     SerialNumber = SerialNumber + 1
     Counter = Counter + 1
 Wend

'Save the next number back to the Settings.txt file ready for the next use.
System.PrivateProfileString("W:\settings.txt", "MacroSettings", _
         "SerialNumber") = SerialNumber

'Recreate the bookmark ready for the next use.
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
     .Add Name:="SerialNumber", Range:=Rng1
 End With
End Sub
```

Question:

- How can I convert this to use the document name as the "settings.txt" file
- How can I convert this to save the "settings.txt" file in the same location as the document location automatically. (I'm not 100% sure but I think I have to create setting.txt manually, I'd like the creation to be automatic)
- If I am going about this the wrong way, please let me know

My thought process would be:

```
If "document_name.txt" exists then do run macro

If "settings/document_name.txt" DOESN'T exists then do create document_name.txt in current open files location
and use current document name.
```

Note: I also opened a bounty on this question to have the macro run automatically after user hits print as per normal. Currently they have to manually run macro to print.

[Running a macro before printing a word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909968/running-a-macro-before-printing-a-word-document#)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store the number in a Custom Document Property or a Document variable in the documents concerned?

Comment: No that sounds preferable, this is just a code snippet I found.

Comment: I just need the number to increment every time it's printed

Comment: And what is supposed to happen if someone chooses to print, say, 5 copies? Does the counter increment by 1, or by 5?

Comment: By one, the idea is to have a unique number on each copy of the same one-page document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you could use a macro like:

```
Sub FilePrint()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With ActiveDocument
  j = CLng(InputBox("How many copies to print?", "Print Copies"))
  For i = 1 To j
    With .CustomDocumentProperties("Counter")
      .Value = .Value + 1
    End With
    .Fields.Update
    .PrintOut
  Next
  .Save
End With
End Sub
```

coupled with a Custom Document Property named 'Counter', whose value you initially set to 0. Should you need to re-set the counter for some reason, simply edit the 'Counter' Custom Document Property accordingly.

Then, wherever you want the count to appear, add a DOCPROPERTY field that references the 'Counter' property. You can do this via Insert|Quick Parts|Field, or by pressing Ctrl-F9 to create a pair of field braces (ie '{}') and typing 'DOCPROPERTY Counter' between them, so that you end up with '{DOCPROPERTY Counter}'. You can use a numeric picture switch in the DOCPROPERTY field to format the number to have a particular lenght (e.g. 4 diigits). In that case the field code would appear as '{DOCPROPERTY Counter # 0000}'. When you're done, press F9 to update the field. You can then copy & paste the field to wherever else you might want also it to appear in your document.

If the documents you want this to apply to share a common template, but that template isn't used for other documents also, you could simply add the macro to that template; otherwise you might need to add it to each of the documents concerned and save them in the docm or doc format.

Comment: It is NOT copied directly from msofficeforums and, even if it were, I am the author of the post you accuse me of not giving credit to. The code, for example, is entirely different to what I posted at msofficeforums, as your needs are different. Your inability to follow instructions doesn't invalidate the answer given.

Comment: Fair enough I just noticed I recognized the text, I will give it a test and see if I can get any specific errors