# Make Individual Serial for Print documents in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, document

**Dear Readers**

I am trying to make individual Serial numbers ( incrementing number) for some Forms in Microsoft Word, so we can track each one of them much simpler between people.
I used this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1329783/print-serial-number-or-incrementing-number-in-word-document-footer) and it did work,
but it needs always running Macro and I couldn't figure out how to make it automatic with just a simple Ctrl+P shortcut, so I used this [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909968/running-a-macro-before-printing-a-word-document) for that reason,
finally, it looked so great but there is a problem since the second link is a just "before Print" code, there is always one extra print at the end since the Printing process starts exactly after macro ended. any cancel print process code out there?

**how can I overcome this one?**

Codes under the document

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
Register_Event_Handler
End Sub
```

Codes under the Module

```
Dim X As New EventClassModule
Sub Register_Event_Handler()
Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

Codes under the class

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)

' Run code directly inside this Sub OR
MsgBox "Before Print"

' Call another Sub here, note, Sub and Module name can't match
Call FilePrint
' See https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/wiki/compile-error-expected-variable-or-procedure-not-module-macros-microsoft-office-29982732.html
End Sub
```

and finally Codes of FilePrint section as a Module

```
Sub FilePrint()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With ActiveDocument
  j = CLng(InputBox("How many copies to print?", "Print Copies"))
  For i = 1 To j
    With .CustomDocumentProperties("Counter")
      .Value = .Value + 1
    End With
    .Fields.Update
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1
  Next
  .Save
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming that your code is contained in the document that you are trying to control you don't need the event handler. All you need to do is rename `FilePrint` to `PrintPreviewAndPrint` and it will respond to Ctrl+P. To allow the user to cancel just check the value of `j` to see if it is greater than zero.

Comment: I did this, didn't work

Comment: Take a look at Word MVP Graham Mayor's page on numbering documents: http://www.gmayor.com/automatic_numbering_documents.htm